# Polynomial ring and maximal ideal

Tags: ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I am really stump in this problem. Prove that $(x,y)$ and $(2,x,y)$ are prime ideals in $Z[x,y]$ but only the latter ideal is a maximal ideal.

Comment: You can try looking at the quotient rings for these two ideals.

Comment: There is no such thing as an ideal in a polynomial. These are ideals in a polynomial *ring*.

Comment: yeah you are correct it is just a new concept to me and i was trying to come up with a title for the question.

Comment: Wby not just edit the title to read. " . . . polynomial *ring* . . ."?  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ring homomorphism $\mathbf{Z}$[x,y] $\to Z$ given by $\phi(f(x,y))=f(0,0)$. Clearly $\phi$ is surjective and $ ker \phi =(x,y)$ (not hard to prove). As for the other, you can consider a homomorhism (same way) from $\mathbf{Z}$[x,y] to $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ .

Comment: Did it go fine? (Thanks for asking the question by the way, I realised that such rings can have infinitely many maximal ideal)